# Synchronous destruction through std::shared_ptr<T>::reset()

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14

Consider the following simplified program modelling a real scenario where different users can make concurrent requests to the same resource:

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct T {
    void op() { /* some stuff */ }
    ~T() noexcept { /* some stuff */ }
};

std::shared_ptr<T> t;
std::mutex mtx;
std::weak_ptr<T> w{t};
enum action { destroy, op};

void request(action a) {
    if (a == action::destroy) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lk{mtx};
        t.reset();
        std::cout << "*t certainly destroyed\n";
    } else if (a == action::op) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lk{mtx};
        if (auto l = w.lock()) {
            l->op();
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // At some point in time and different points in the program,
    // two different users make two different concurrent requests
    std::thread th1{request, destroy}; std::thread th2{request, op};

    // ....
    th2.join();
    th1.join();
}
```

I am not asking if the program is formally correct - I think it is, but I have never seen this approach for guaranteeing a **synchronous destruction** of a resource shared via smart pointers. I personally think it is fine and has a valid use.

However, I am wondering if others think the same and, in case, if there are more elegant alternatives apart from the classic synchronization with `unique_lock`s and condition variables and from introducing modifications (e.g. atomic flags) to `T`.

It would be ideal if I could even get rid of the `mtx` somehow.

Comment: Looks legit. The usual warning applies that `T::op` needs to be correct when called concurrently.

Comment: But the shared_ptr is never initialized to anything? And you're forced to do it at file-level scope?

Comment: all the variables are initialized in the real program.

Comment: yes, it's fine. the reference counting in the shared_ptr is atomic and the locked copy stays in scope for the duration of the op, so the object can't be destroyed during the op. You can probably do away with the mutex by using the atomic_swap/atomic_load and atomic_store overloads for shared_ptr<>. Need to think about that before I put it in an answer though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ read the code in the example better. It's minimal, complete and verified. It's just not the real case.

Comment: @Martin At least I can [confirm that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6515265d766e8da).I just said such statement smells fishy.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It doesn't initialize `t`, so the weak_ptr.lock always fails, but also a quick look at godbolt shows that the compiler eliminates the call to `op()` entirely, so even if it didn't fail we couldn't disambiguate. *HOWEVER* I think for the purposes of annotating the question it's fine. I'm only making these points to clarify that @Martin should not rely on this code as a proof...

Comment: @kfsone I said it smells fishy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. The reference counting in the shared_ptr is atomic and the locked copy stays in scope for the duration of the op, so the object can't be destroyed during the op.

In this case the mutex is not actually protecting the lifetime of T, but sequencing calls to `op()` and destruction. If you don't mind multiple concurrent calls to `op()`, or the destruction time being indeterminate (i.e. after the last running `op()` has completed) then you can do away with it, since `std::shared_ptr<>::reset()` and `std::weak_ptr<>::lock()` are both thread-safe.

However, I would advise caution as the author clearly meant for calls to `op()` to be serialised.